# quick question about remote ssh

Tags: ssh

I'm wondering if editing remote files via ssh is 100% safe on public networks. I use some software called phpDesigner with has remote ssh editing capabilities built in so I'm wondering if I'm in a coffee shop for with public wifi if connecting over ssh is safe for me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, the connection will be encrypted. But unless you are using your own computer, you may be leaving traces on the computer in the coffee shop.

Comment: it's on my laptop, I was just wondering if someone could intercept the communications between my laptop and the server, such as username/password for ssh.

Comment: No. The entire communication, including authentication (password or key file) is encrypted.

Comment: Just one note: if you connected to the server before, then the server's host key will be stored on your laptop. So the next time you connect, SSH verifies that it's communicating with that very same server. If not, a warning is printed. See http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-host-key-protection. So I recommend you establish a first connection to the server from a secure location.

Answer (score 1):

The traffic will be encrypted so username and password will not be visible, but you should only accept connections using public key certificates since this is more secure than just a password.

[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-an-ssh-certificate-for-ubuntu-from-a-mac) is an example of how to set this up from a mac to an ubuntu server.